# Facebook oAuth authentication

Tags: facebook, oauth, authentication

I have a small doubt , I am using facebook javascript sdk to authenticate users against their facebook account. Once the validation is done i can retrieve the required informaiton form the users profile such as full name,date of birth , email , username etc ...

No in my application , other users are required to register , and I will be storing their information. i mean specifically a username and a password.

But with the facebook  users how am i to keep their information ? I can store their username and obviously they dont have a password but the token or their facebook id hashed as the password , but that makes my application unsecured.

I am quite puzzled with this problem. Any help would be great.

Regards,

Gayan

Comment: [http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-your-users-with-facebook-connect/](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-your-users-with-facebook-connect/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you want to treat users that come from Facebook?

1. Do you want to provide Facebook-only authentication OR
2. Do you want just to have an access to user FB wall, friends, etc. and use your own authentication method, like for "classic" user?

If (2), you can save user's Facebook ID and token in your database and use them when you need them. This would be quite safe, because token is associated exclusively with your app and given privileges.

Comment: hi , i want them to provide only facebook authentication. I think its possible to do the same stackoverflow does. Each time i login with my google account , but i will still have to fill the registration detail. SO this will only ease the customer to remember one login.

Comment: Understood. Have you read [this article](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)?

Comment: Yeah , i went trough the documentation. Quite massive but really helpful.